# Partial Sum Test for convergence or divergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Given the following series,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)$$

I am trying to prove if it diverges or converges.

I used the partial sum test and found that the nth partial sum of this series is,

$$\ln(2)-\ln(n+1)-\ln(n+2)$$

Therefore taking the limit of this partial sum to see if it converges to a number we see that it converges to infinity.

So is this enough to prove that the above series diverges by the nth parial sum test?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The partial sums diverge to $-\infty$ and hence the series diverges.

Comment: thanks for your help, just wanted to clear that up in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES.Because the definition of $x=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$ is that $x=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^nA_j$.